Diffraction of water waves through a gap

Hello,
This question is from CIE alevel physics Oct/Nov 2006 paper 01.
It seems to be a weird question without a graph.
The textbook states that the diffraction effect is greatest when the gap width is equal to the wavelength of the wave passing through.
If one assumes the size of the gap is smaller than the wavelength of the water waves, then A, B, C are all correct. If one assumes that the size of the gap is larger than the wavelength of the water waves, then D is correct. Therefore, D must be the right answer, which is the correct answer in the official mark scheme.
But if so, it seems to be more of a logic question than physics one.
What are your thoughts?
Thank you.

The diffraction equation is:
$$d \sin (\theta) = n \lambda = nv/f$$
More diffraction is bigger $\sin(\theta)$, which is effectively the same as bigger $\theta$. It's now straightforward to see that D is the correct answer.
If the size of the gap is smaller than the wavelength of the water waves ($d < \lambda$) then the slit acts as a point source that radiates in all directions, which is similar to there being infinite diffraction. It's therefore impossible to increase the diffraction in that case, ergo, the size of the gap must be larger than the wavelength of the water waves.

Thank you for your explanation.

You are right that the question of diffraction can be confusing without a graph, especially when discussing the relationship between the gap size and the wavelength.
Diffraction is greatest when the gap size is comparable to the wavelength. When the wavelength is roughly equal to the gap size, the most noticeable wave bending occurs. If the gap size is smaller than the wavelength, diffraction will be significant, since the wave will bend around the edge a lot. When the gap size is larger than the wavelength, diffraction will be weaker, and the wave will be more in a straight line.
In your question, if the gap size is smaller than the wavelength, then A, B, and C are correct, since diffraction is stronger, and the wave bending effects will be more pronounced. If the gap size is larger than the wavelength, then D is correct, since the wave will travel in a straighter line, and diffraction will be weaker.
So your guess that D is the correct answer when the gap size is larger is indeed logical, when considering the effect of the gap size on diffraction.  This has a lot to do with understanding how a wave interacts with an object. Diffraction as a phenomenon is not just physics, but also the logic of how a wave will propagate depending on the geometry of the medium.
